# Is this Composition violating any principle of Object-Oriented Programming?

Tags: c#, oop, composition

Say I have the following two classes:

```
public class MyDevice
{
    int id;
    string name;
    // other resources

    public MyChannel CreateChannel()
    {
        return new MyChannel(this);
    }
} 

public class MyChannel
{
    int id;
    MyDevice _device;
    // other resources        

    public MyChannel(MyDevice device)
    {
        _device = device;
    }
}
```

In reality each device can have a variable number of channels. So the relationship is that each device has-a collection of channels. It is bothering me that the way the code is written a `MyChannel` object has-a `MyDevice` object. However, the relationship defined in code is more convenient and I also want to keep it simple.

To pacify the nagging in the back of my head - I keep pointing to the way that `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` are structured where each `SqlCommand` object has-a `SqlConnection` object despite the fact that each SQL connection has-a series of SQL commands.

Am I violating any principle of object-oriented programming/ does this code smell?

***Edit:***

Explicitly: **Is turning the has-a relationship on it's head a big no-no in terms of Object-Oriented design?** If so, what is a single principle that is ignored/neglected?

Comment: I don't actually think this is on topic for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @juharr This seems to be example code which is off-topic on Code Review. Being on-topic at Code Review and off-topic at Stack Overflow are not the same thing. Being on-topic at Code Review is not a close reason. If you feel this is off-topic for Stack Overflow for a reason defined in the help center, vote to close for that reason.

Comment: Is it not a programming question? Seems completely on-topic to me. The division of these questions to other stack exchange sites just makes it harder for programmers to find answers - the original intent of the site.

Comment: @BlueRebel -- Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I read it... I'm not following. Are suggesting this question is subjective? It's possible, but if so please state that. It seems to me a legitimate question looking for guidance.

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." -- The question is fairly open-ended as there is no definitive answer.  "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here." -- again, the fact that it's open-ended potentially leads to a discussion much like we're having right now.

Comment: The question is defined and given a decent scope. The member is looking for specific guidance. It's not open-ended in the "What makes for good composition rules" sense, there's a very specific example given. Yes, we're having a discussion, but it's about the validity of the question, not the question itself. We've gone meta.

Comment: @roryap: With all due respect, the discussion you are having is due to a disagreement of the level of subjectivity that this question entails. My question is: **Is turning the has-a relationship on it's head a big no-no in terms of design?** So is it ever okay or is it the stuff of nightmares - if so what is a *single design principle* that is being ignored?

Comment: I see your point and retract my argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume where the example says `Device` its meant to be `MyDevice`.  You basically have a reference to the channels parent i.e. the device.  I don't think this break OO and in many cases is useful.  The purists will say it breaks encapsulation of the parent and creates a coupling from the channel to anything outside channel and beyond.

Comment: I really like the point of adding a reference to the parent object. I have been thinking about cases within the .NET Framework where this approach is used - thus far I was thinking mainly about ADO.NET data provider objects, but adding a reference to the owner/ parent is used extensively in the WinForms API.

Comment: If you ever use a tree control having a reference from a node to its parent node is very useful for iterating back up the tree, to find a root node for example.

Answer (score 2):

This is not violating any prinicpals. You will frequently have objects containing other objects.

I assume you meant to have the MyChannel._device field to actually be a MyDevice?

Also, you may want to consider having a list of MyChannel objects within the MyDevice object, to make two-way traversal easier, if you have a need. Just make sure you enforce consistency between the two fields.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's anything in principle wrong with this pattern. Sometimes, two classes exist which are genuinely tightly coupled.

But, I do think it would be a very good idea for you to make your channel class private, and *only* instantiate it using the CreateChannel method, while adding a private collection of channel objects with a public getter and no public setter as a member of your device. That way, you can make sure that your device class is always in control of its own channels.